# RegisterReceiver for PendingIntent from notification

Tags: android, android-intent, notifications, intentfilter

I'm displaying a notification at some point which will open an activity (Activity A) when tapped. I've tried to register a receiver with an IntentFilter to listen for the user tapping the notification. What I want is, avoid the system launching again the activity when Activity A is already present. Sadly, the receiver is never being called.

This is the code launching the notification:

```
//Create the BackStack for the back navigation when opening from intent
TaskStackBuilder builder = TaskStackBuilder.create(this);

//Create the intent to open this activity, allowing the implementing class add some parameters
Intent thisClassIntent = new Intent(this, ActivityA.class);
onPrepareIntent(thisClassIntent);
thisClassIntent.setAction(ACTION_OPEN_CHAT);

builder.addParentStack(this);
builder.addNextIntent(thisClassIntent);

PendingIntent pendingIntent = builder.getPendingIntent(0, 
PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

Notification.Builder builder = new Notification.Builder(context).setContentTitle("some title")
                .setContentText("some text")
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.icon)
                .setPriority(Notification.PRIORITY_MAX)
                .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_ALL)
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

Notification notification = builder.build();
NotificationManager manager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        manager.notify(0, notification);
```

In this Activity, I tried to listen for the Action defined in the intent:

```
public class ActivityA extends AppCompatActivity {

private BroadcastReceiver mReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        //This should be called when the user taps in the notification
    }
};

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    registerReceiver(mReceiver, new IntentFilter(ACTION_OPEN_CHAT));
}

...
}
```

Would be great if you got any clue. 
Thanks!

Comment: are you declaring the intent that will activate your broadcast receiver in your android manifest?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `PendingIntent` created by `TaskStackBuilder` is for `Activity` targets, not `BroadcastReceiver` targets.  If you want to have your notification send a specialized broadcast, you'll need to create your own `PendingIntent` for a `BroadcastReceiver` and have your `Activity` register a receiver for it.